# Undefined is not a function in React Native project

Tags: android, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm new to React Native. I'm trying to open existing React Native project in the emulator on Windows 10, but it throws this error:

```
undefined is not a function (evaluating '(0, _reactRedux.combineReducers)')
```

I'm using 0.45.1 version of React Native. Why is this happening?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`combineReducers`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html) is a utility function *exported by `redux`*, not `react-redux`. It's not React-specific and it's a utility function so it's from the `redux` package. You're trying to import it from `react-redux` so it's undefined because it doesn't exist there, and when you try to execute the function it throws the error. Import it from `redux`:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
```

Comment: When I installed dependencies on Windows, it set Redux's path as node_modules/react-redux. So I imported it from react-redux.

Comment: @PirateofMarmara What do you mean? Redux and React Redux are separate packages.

Comment: I now installed Redux package. I thought Redux and React Redux are the same packages. That error has gone but new one came up: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeParse2.default.Object.extend').

Comment: @PirateofMarmara Where does that error occur? Does it mention a line? You may want to post that s a different question with your code, since it's out of the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I'll post it as a different question with its details.